# Allowing users to upload ANYTHING

Tags: php

I'm building a file sharing site, and I'm thinking, I want my users to be able to upload and share anything.

Sounds dangerous, I know. But, is there a method to allow this to be possible? For example, forcing the download when the user requests the link with a mime type? Rather than "running" something on the page.

Any ideas how to allow any file type without the security issue.

Thanks

Comment: Most browsers block the automatic download of executables, but the user can accept the prompt and ignore the warning. Are you asking how to circumvent this warning?

Comment: I'm confused. Your question title and first sentence talks about allowing uploading and your second sentence talks about forcing downloading. I have no idea what you're talking about. Then your third says asks about "how to allow a filetype" but with no clear context -- allow by what, allow in what, allow for what purpose?

Comment: also, you have posted no code. without code, it's more difficult to help you even if your question did make sense

Comment: I would upload a .php file that deletes your directories, sound dangerous?

Comment: Megaupload and Rapidshare can do it, so it's possible.

Comment: I can do "it" also, though it depends upon the meaning of "it"

Comment: @horatio you're talking useless garbage. Megaupload and Rapidshare allow you to upload any file type, dangerous or not, yet their servers are secure. So, it's obviously possible, it's just half the idiots here would rather pick faults with everything else but answer the question because the truth is they don't have a clue how to answer the question.

Comment: You haven't defined what you are asking. In fact what you just posted is closer to an explanation of your question. If you were to take a moment and re-read your own question without assuming people are mind readers, you will notice a high level of ambiguity. You also ignored the people who asked you direct questions: see the first four questions above and then look at your response to them.

Comment: So why is it possible that Topener, and other members, are able to understand what I am saying? The question is clear, I want user to upload and host ANY file type on my servers without making my server unsecure. Now, the problem is people see it and think "OMG THIS IS DANGEROUS, THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE" without even researching before they answer. Which then bogs down my whole question and induces lots of negative votes. Topener's answer has opened another door for me to venture down that's proving to be the solution. How was Topener able to understand my question if it's definition is poor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Store the file on a location not accessible by the user through the browser. (so above the document root)
2. when loading a file, use the `readfile()` function.
3. Set correct headers, including these:

   ```
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=[INSERT FILENAME HERE]");
   ```

   And also use the correct content-type header for each type of file

Comment: Interesting! Are there any security precautions with this solution though?

Comment: always make sure the file doesn't get executed on the server, because it could harm your server. Aside from that, I would not see any major risks

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate the response, and after some research this appears to be the solution a number of people using when running limitless file storage servers.

Comment: @JamesJeffery (and Topener): this is indeed a good approach. Make sure you take `location not accessible by the user through the browser` to mean: somewhere **above** the document root and not: I'll just hide the directory with some directives in `.htaccess` or something similar. Because if the server's configuration is accidentally compromised at one point in the future somehow (overruling `.htaccess` rules for instance), the files could then still be accessible through a browser again.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it to be dangerous to other users (as they will be sharing virus ridden files in no time), but provide some protection for your web server from code injection attacks, you might consider storing the uploads in a database BLOB field. That should at least make it harder to inject code that will run on the server.

Comment: Would this add a huge load to the SQL server when downloading large files?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow users to upload anything by using a simple [HTML multipart form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) along with [PHP's $_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). Only issue I see is file size limits.

You than can simply post a link to any of these files. It's the user's browsers settings that determine if a file is executed or downloaded, not yours. So you can suggest that they right click on them, and select 'save to', but besides that it's limited.

Answer (score -1):

> Any ideas how to allow any filetype without the security issue.

You say it yourself. It's like wanting to make scrambled eggs, without wanting to break the eggs.